# Synchronize Elasticsearch index with SQL Server table

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, node-mssql

Is there any way to listen to SQL Server database changes (e.g. insert, update) from my node.js application?

I want to keep my elasticsearch index synchronized with my database. And I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: You surely could use triggers but there must be some simpler choices too I take.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Take a look at CLR triggers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/dev-guide/clr-triggers?view=sql-server-2014

Then at message passing tool, like RabbitMQ, https://www.rabbitmq.com/

so essentially, we are talking abut Trigger CLR sending messages through RabbbitMQ and nodejs receiving it.

This blog post might be helpful.

https://nielsberglund.com/2017/02/11/rabbitmq---sql-server/ and here, https://github.com/nberglund/RabbitMQ-SqlServer

Comment: Simpler solution might be just polling.

Comment: How can polling be done on server side?

Comment: It can't. If initiated on the MSSQL then that will be pushing, not polling. If polling then then the action would be initiated on the nodejs every x seconds, minutes or hours.

Comment: Oh ok. So basically I'll be checking the databae every x seconds for any updates. Is that so?

Comment: Yes.  That's a simpler alternative to pushing described earlier.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to fetch just the newly added data from a table?

Comment: UTC timestamps might just do. But there might be even simpler way, take a look at the Service Broker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-2017



And this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlssb

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot!!

Comment: This might also be interesting, though a bit outdated: https://github.com/No9/sqlcdcstream